# How to handle null/undefined properties when applying updates using the spread syntax?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Consider this example method

```
GetCustomerWithPoints(customerId: number): Customer {
  const customer = this.customerService.getCustomer(customerId);
  const points = this.pointService.getPointsForCustomer(customerId);

   return {...customer, [customer.rewards.points]: points };
}
```

How to handle the case where `customer.rewards` is `null` or `undefined`?  I don't care about setting the points if the `rewards` object is null, I only want to set them when `rewards` object exists.

With the above code I am getting the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

Comment: `if (customer.rewards == null) return customer`?

Comment: @Bergi while your code will work, I want to learn how to do it in the spread operator /assignment itself, if its possible.  The code above is just a sample so you understand what I am asking, what if I have possibly multiple properties that can be null? do i have to change them outside of the assignment?

Comment: I recommend simple assignments then (`if (customer.rewards) newCustomer[customer.rewards.points] = points;`). You can put it in an object literal with spread syntax using `...(customer.rewards ? {[customer.rewards.points]: points} : null)` but imo that's ugly.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, i agree with you, but I couldn't figure out the conditional syntax before, just wanted to understand how to make it work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the actual value to be defined first. Then, only access to it when you know it's safe to do so:

```js
GetCustomerWithPoints(customerId: number): Customer {
  const customer = this.customerService.getCustomer(customerId);
  const points = this.pointService.getPointsForCustomer(customerId);
  if(!customer.rewards) {
    // rewards is null or undefined, just return the customer 
    return customer
  }
  // rewards are defined, append them to the customer:
  return {...customer, [customer.rewards.points]: points };
}
```

You can also use a short-hand alternative:

```js
GetCustomerWithPoints(customerId: number): Customer {
  const customer = this.customerService.getCustomer(customerId);
  const points = this.pointService.getPointsForCustomer(customerId);

  return {
    ...customer, 
    ...(customer.rewards ? {[customer.rewards.points]: points} : {}) 
  };
}
```